# Should I take loan from the bank at 1% interest or be forced to pay 9% interest by failing to pay rent?

Tags: riba, debt

Something happened and I lost my job, and I didn't have enough money to pay the flat rent.

Here in Sweden if your late in paying rent, what they do is they start to take interest on the rent until you pay it. I couldn't pay it and I'm still looking for job.

They take 9% interest. I'm thinking about taking a loan from a bank with a lower 1% interest and pay my rent with the loan. That way I will be forced to pay 1% instead of 9%.

I know that interest is forbidden in religion, but I'm forced to do it.

So, should I take loan from the bank or should I just leave it with a higher rate? Would I be doing an other sin by taking loan from the bank to pay my flat debt?

Comment: I never knew you could get a loan in Sweden from the bank with 1% interest, especially without a job... and i doubt it. If you are renting a flat in Sweden and cannot afford to pay the rent due to different issues, you can get free help from the social services.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have to know that in the first case (when you have to pay interest on rent) is not in your hands. You did not intended for this to happen, you were just caught in it.

But, in case of taking loan from bank, it's my personal suggestion that it will be interest over more interest, which will surely create more problems for you. You have to wait until you get a job and and pray to Allah that you may get it at the right time.

In the first case, you are not doing sin, but in second case (to take loan from bank on interest) is surely a sin, so I would say that try to avoid the second one.

Comment: So choosing the lesser of the evil is not a good option?

Comment: @Farhan: which is lesser of evil?

Comment: Paying lesser riba (1% interest vs 9%)! I do understand your logic, but looking at the complete picture, OP will be spending more of his money in riba if he does NOT take that bank loan. However, he DID know before renting the flat that if he doesn't pay the rent on time, he has to pay 9% interest. How is that not a sin (which you mentioned as the first case)? I'm sure he did not intend to run into that situation, he has no other choice at this moment.

Comment: actually he had no intention already of Not paying the rent at all. everyone believes that they will have money to pay the rent. regarding the lesser evil, i am not a qualified scholar, so i believe a scholar should be consulted in this way.

Comment: Reference? Proof? Anything?

Answer (score 0):

Assalamu Alaikum...
Those who take riba (involved in usury) are doing Zulm (hurting) the borrowers.
I firmly support Farhan's answer.
I suggest you to ask god to give you strength and patience to bear this problem.
Trust Allah, verily he is the best of the providers.
Now, your situation is like, both your owner and the bank are doing zulm on you.
So I would suggest you to find a house with a lesser rent where you feel you're sure you can pay the rent in time and avoid penalties or if you can't do that,
hard to swallow step,
evacuate it as it is a luxury for you and manage without a house until you find a good job.
May Allah guide us all.

Comment: huh ... manage without a house ???

Comment: @Ahmed, it is a difficult step I know. I strongly would look for other options like, -> Find a cheaper house which I can probably afford. -> Ask a friend for financial help. -> Start off with a job with a lesser pay first, and keep looking for better jobs. -> Stay with my parents or family. etc. -> If I have a car, I would sleep in a car, and use public restrooms. -> Or get free help from social services if they're available as Kilise suggested under the question above -> etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if the Bank lends you money at 1%, go for it and save the 8%.  You are paying the bank 'rent' for the use of their money.  Usury or charging unreasonable rate of interest is bad in any society because the intent is bad. Standard interest rates are ok to pay and receive in the 21st century.
@Daniel. We have to understand that charging usurus and unreasonable rate of interest by taking advantage of the borrower's plight is not permitted. But charging a reasonable rate of interest for the use of money by borrower is ok because 1400 years ago things were different from now.  In the example, borrowing at 1% is reasonable and fair.  So use of intellect must prevail and the intent if honorable must prevail.  A muslim must know the difference between right and wrong. God knows what is in your heart.
@Daniel, I am glad you used your intellect and agree that 1% interest is not usury. As for pork, not eating it will not cause any  hardship and therefore avoid it because it is specifically forbidden. So allow intellect to play its part in this day and age and dop the right thing because Allah is knows everything and what is in your heart.

Comment: You're going to have to justify your answer. This goes against the standard understanding of the rule, so you'll need to show why this is the case.

Comment: I agree that 1% interest is considered reasonable at least in most non-Muslim parts of the world. But eating pork is also considered reasonable, yet Islam does not permit that. So why do you think that something being reasonable (e.g. charging 1% interest) automatically implies permissibility in Islam?

Answer (score 0):

Paying $1 in interest is less of a sin than paying $9.

Similarly, paying 1% interest on a loan is less of sin than paying 9%.

I'd take out the loan as it is the lesser of two evils.

Allah knows best.

Comment: Reference to support your opinion?